# AltGr not working as keyboard level 3 chooser

Tags: kali-linux, keyboard, keyboard-layout, xkb

I have an almost fresh install of Kali linux as secondary system on my laptop, which has a standard German 101 keys keyboard. After install the AltGr was working perfectly well as a level 3 chooser key (to access @, ~ and |, which are essential for me, specially in linux), but after I did `apt-get upgrade` and messed around `/etc/default/keyboard` it stopped working completelly.

After restoring the file to default (which I'm not sure how was set after install, but I'm pretty sure it was with `XKBOPTIONS=" "` ), and changing the keyboard layout both through the configurations menu and by running `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`, the AltGr key is not working at all for these keys, strangelly, it shows this `ˇ` symbol when I try to do `|`, the rest just doesn't work.

Also, not only the AltGr is not working but any other key I set to level 3 chooser by directly changing `/etc/default/keyboard` also doesn't work. Actually, any level 3 option I set in the file at `XKBOPTIONS` seems to be of no effect at all.

Yes I rebooted after each change and yes the AltGr key is working as it works in Windows.

Any help is appreciated.